# Why subcomponent can't have the same scope as its parent component in dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2

I read [one tutorial](https://dagger.dev/subcomponents.html) which talks about the concept of "component" and "Scope" in Dagger. It says:

> No subcomponent may be associated with the same scope as any ancestor
>   component

I understand what it says, but it doesn't explain clearly why subcomponent can't be associated with the same scope as its parent component.

Though it has explained a little :

> Because a subcomponent is created from within its parent, its lifetime
>   is strictly smaller than its parent’s.

But why can't subcomponent and its parent component have the same lifetime that's have the same scope?

Could someone please explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in the link posted by you:

> Because a subcomponent is created from within its parent, its lifetime is strictly smaller than its parent’s. That means that it makes sense to consider subcomponents’ scopes as “smaller” and parent components’ scopes as “larger”

The parent component will be created first, then the subcomponent. So the subcomponent lifetime starts "after" the lifetime of the parent component. So they don't have the same scope.